# Window.open - How to open contents of another file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
/**
 * This Component contains buttons for loading the data from the database,
 * opening data, and saving the data
 * 
 * 
 */

import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import NewWindow from 'react-new-window';


/*
This function creates a component for the buttons. 
*/
class LoadData extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

    /**Fetch request for the raw data from the express server */
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/api/getAllData')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({data})
        });
    }

    /** response for the Load button */
    pressedLoad = () => {
        for(let i = 0; i < this.state.data.length; i++) {
            this.props.parentCallback( "add" ,this.state.data[i]);
        }
    };

    /** response for the Open button */
    pressedOpen = () => {
        this.props.parentCallback( "open" );
    }

    /** response for the Graph button */
    pressedGraph = () => {
        this.props.parentCallback("graph");
    }

    /** response for the Select Range Button */
    pressedRange = () => {

    }

    openNewWindow = () => {
        let features = 'menubar=yes,location=yes,resizeable=yes,scrollbar=yes,status=yes';

        document.getElementById('multiSeriesChart').addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
            let url = 'http://localhost:3000/';
            let other = window.open(url, "_blank", features);
        });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <title>Program Controller</title>
                <h1>Program Controls: </h1>
                <button onClick={this.pressedLoad}>Load Data</button>
                <button id="multiSeriesChart" onClick={this.openNewWindow}>Open Multi-Series Graph</button>
            </div>
        );
    };
};

export default LoadData;
```

```css
class Screen extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            /** The array containing all of the raw data from the psql server */
            data:[],
            /**
             * Represents which button is pressed under the "Column to display"
             * Options include: 'occupancy', 'adr', 'revpar', 'supply', 'demand', 'revenue', 'cprops', 'crooms', 'sparts'
             */
            graphDisplay: false,
            /** Represents which button is pressed under "with respect to"
             * options include: 'month', 'average per year', 'average per season'
             */
            graphxSelect: "month",
            /**
             * Represents which option is selected from the button menu 
             * under/attached to the Multi series chart
             */
            multiChartOption: 1,
            /**The info to be displayed on the Statistics Screen */
            statisticsData: {
                catagory: "",
                average: 0,
                range: 0,
                median: 0,
                min: 0,
                max: 0
            },
            pieData: {
                year: 0,
                dataPoints : [{y: 95, label: "stan"}]
            },
            barChartOptions: {
                xValue: 0
            }
        }
    }
    
    openNewWindow = () => {
        let features = 'menubar=yes,location=yes,resizeable=yes,scrollbar=yes,status=yes';

        document.getElementById('chart').addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
            let url = 'http://localhost:3000/';
            let other = window.open(url, "_blank", features);
        });
    }



    /** Render the buttons and graph */
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="screen">
            <div className="topButtons">
            </div>  

                <Tabs>
                        <div label="Program Controller">
                            <LoadData parentCallback = {this.loadDataCallback}/>
                        </div>
                        <div label="Raw Data Table">
                            <RawDataTable dataFromParent = {this.state} className="dataTable" />
                        </div>
                        <div label="Statistics">
                            <Statistics dataFromParent = {this.state} parentCallback = {this.statisticsCallback} /> 
                        </div>
                        <div label="First Graph">
                            <FirstGraph dataFromParent = {this.state} parentCallback = {this.graphButtonCallBack} parentBarChartCallback = {this.barChartCallback} className="canvasGraph" />
                        </div>
                        <div label="Bar Chart">
                            <BarChart dataFromParent = {this.state} parentCallback = {this.barChartCallback}/>
                        </div>
                </Tabs>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Screen
```

```html
/**
 * This is the component class for the Multi Series Chart
 * 
 */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CanvasJSReact from '../../canvasjs.react';
var CanvasJS = CanvasJSReact.CanvasJS;
var CanvasJSChart = CanvasJSReact.CanvasJSChart;

class MultiSeriesChart extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.toggleDataSeries = this.toggleDataSeries.bind(this);
    }
    
       /** Parent callback for the first button*/
    clicked1 = () => {
        this.props.parentCallback(1)
    }

    /** Parent callback for the second button*/
    clicked2 = () => {
        this.props.parentCallback(2)
    }

    /** Parent callback for the third button*/
    clicked3 = () => {
        this.props.parentCallback(3)
    }

    render() {

        /** Chart Options/parameters */
        const options = {
            animationEnabled: true, 
            theme: "dark1",
            title:{
                text: "Multi Series Chart"
            },
            subtitles: [{
                text: ""
            }],
            axisX: {
                title: "Date"
            },
            axisY: this.getLeftAxis(),
            axisY2: this.getRightAxis(),
            toolTip: {
                shared: true
            },
            legend: {
                cursor: "pointer",
                itemclick: this.toggleDataSeries
            },
            data: this.loadGraphData()
        }
        
        
        return (
            <div className="multiSeriesChart">
                <CanvasJSChart options = {options} onRef={ref => this.chart = ref}/>
                {/*You can get reference to the chart instance as shown above using onRef. This allows you to access all chart properties and methods*/}
                <button onClick={this.clicked1} > Revenue vs Units </button>
                <button onClick={this.clicked2}> Revenue vs Percentage </button>
                <button onClick={this.clicked3}> Percentage vs Units </button>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default MultiSeriesChart
```

I have a quick question about the `window.open()` function (if that is the issue). I am creating an app in React and I am using `window.open()` to open a graph that I have created in `canvasjs` in another file in its own separate window. My problem is when I click the "Open Multi-Series Graph" button it just opens another window that contains all the contents from the main app again and not just the graph.

I am trying to figure out how to open the graph that is in another file in its own separate window. Thank you!

Below are screenshots of the main page, loadData.js and the multiSeriesChart.js file that houses the graph that I am wanting in its own window:

[image: main page]
[image: loadData.js]
[image: multiSeriesChart.js]

Comment: post code, not images of code

Comment: `const newWindow = window.open(); newWindow.document.write(markup here);`

Comment: I posted what I could

Comment: `let url = 'http://localhost:3000/';
            let other = window.open(url, "_blank", features);` so your window opens up the base URL.... shouldn't it be the route to your code?

Comment: @epascarello do you mean the path to that file that I want it to execute?